# DateTime Conversion Error In Store Procedure Inside Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm facing error like below when I tried to convert datetime string (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm TT) to SQL DateTime in Store Procedure inside Cursor.

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I'm pasting my store procedure below and error throwing at line 131 in `INSERT` statement where converting 2 variables `@var1` & `@var2` to DATETIME.

SQL Server Version:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (X64) Dec 28 2012 20:23:12 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: )

Variable Values For Testing:

```
@Log = "8/6/2015 1:37:00 PM"
@stBreakTimeStart = "1:00 PM"
@stBreakTimeEnd = "2:00 PM"
```

Approximate `@var1` & `@var2` Values For Testing:

```
@var1 = "2015-08-06 1:00 PM"
@var2 = "2015-08-06 2:00 PM"
```

My Store Procedure:

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      KG
-- Create date: 15.09.13
-- Description: Insert all excel file data in EmpInOutAuto table
-- EXEC [insertEmpInOutAuto] '<EmpData><AttendanceData><stEmployeeName>Dexterity</stEmployeeName><inStaffNo>25</inStaffNo><stDepartment>Management</stDepartment><inDevNo>1</inDevNo><dtLog>8/6/2015 1:37:00 PM</dtLog><stState></stState><stMode>In</stMode></AttendanceData></EmpData>',1
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertEmpInOutAuto]
(
@ImportXML XML,
@inTrackExcelSheetId INT
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @intErrorCode INT;

BEGIN TRAN
    INSERT INTO EmpInOutAuto
        (
            [stEmployeeName],
            [inStaffNo],
            [stDepartment],
            [inDevNo],
            [dtLog],
            [stState],
            [stMode],
            [inTrackExcelSheetId]
        )
    SELECT
        Col.value('stEmployeeName[1]', 'NVARCHAR(200)') AS NAME,
        Col.value('inStaffNo[1]', 'INT') AS StaffNo,
        Col.value('stDepartment[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS Dept,
        Col.value('inDevNo[1]', 'INT') AS DevNo,
        Col.value('dtLog[1]', 'DATETIME') AS DateTimeLog,
        Col.value('stState[1]', 'NVARCHAR(200)') AS StateC,
        Col.value('stMode[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS Mode,
        @inTrackExcelSheetId
    FROM
        @ImportXML.nodes('//EmpData/AttendanceData') Tab(Col)


    -- Get BreakTime Data
    DECLARE @stBreakTimeStart NVARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @stBreakTimeEnd NVARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @stFinalBTStart NVARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE @stFinalBTEnd NVARCHAR(20);

    SELECT @stBreakTimeStart=stStartTime, @stBreakTimeEnd=stEndTime
    FROM BreakTime;
    -- End

    DECLARE @EmployeeName NVARCHAR(200);
    DECLARE @StaffNo INT;
    DECLARE @Dept NVARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @DevNo INT;
    DECLARE @Log DATETIME;
    DECLARE @State NVARCHAR(200);
    DECLARE @Mode NVARCHAR(50);

    DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT [stEmployeeName],
                [inStaffNo],
                [stDepartment],
                [inDevNo],
                [dtLog],
                [stState],
                [stMode]
        FROM
                [EmpInOutAuto]
        WHERE
                ISNULL([stMode],'Auto')<>'Auto' AND
                [inTrackExcelSheetId]=@inTrackExcelSheetId
        ORDER BY stEmployeeName ASC, dtLog ASC

        OPEN MyCursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @EmployeeName, @StaffNo, @Dept, @DevNo, @Log, @State, @Mode

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
            BEGIN 

                DECLARE @inEmployeeId INT;
                DECLARE @dtBTStart DATETIME;
                DECLARE @dtBTEnd DATETIME;

                SET @inEmployeeId = (SELECT inEmployeeId FROM Employee WHERE stEmployeeName=@EmployeeName);

                IF @inEmployeeId IS NULL
                BEGIN

                    INSERT INTO Employee
                        (
                            [inEmpRoleId],
                            [stEmployeeCode],
                            [stUserName],
                            [stPassword],
                            [stEmployeeName],
                            [inStaffNo],
                            [stDepartment],
                            [inDevNo],
                            [stState],
                            [inTrackExcelSheetId]
                        )
                    VALUES
                        (
                            (CASE @Dept
                                WHEN 'Management' THEN 2
                                ELSE 3
                            END),
                            @StaffNo,
                            @EmployeeName,
                            (SELECT dbo.getRandomPassword()),
                            @EmployeeName,
                            @StaffNo,
                            @Dept,
                            @DevNo,
                            @State,
                            @inTrackExcelSheetId
                        )

                    SET @inEmployeeId = Scope_Identity();
                END

                DECLARE @var1 NVARCHAR(50);
                SET @var1 = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATE, @Log)) + ' ' + @stBreakTimeStart;
                print(@var1);

                DECLARE @var2 NVARCHAR(50);
                SET @var2 = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATE, @Log)) + ' ' + @stBreakTimeEnd;
                print(@var2);

                INSERT INTO EmpInOut
                    (
                        [inEmployeeId],
                        [dtInOut],
                        [stMode],
                        [dtBreakTimeStart],
                        [dtBreakTimeEnd],
                        [inNumber],
                        [inTrackExcelSheetId]
                    )
                VALUES
                    (
                        @inEmployeeId,
                        @Log,
                        @Mode,
                        CONVERT(DATETIME,@var1),
                        CONVERT(DATETIME,@var2),
                        (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(inNumber),0)+1 FROM EmpInOut WHERE inEmployeeId=@inEmployeeId),
                        @inTrackExcelSheetId
                    )

            FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @EmployeeName, @StaffNo, @Dept, @DevNo, @Log, @State, @Mode
        END  

        CLOSE MyCursor  
        DEALLOCATE MyCursor 

        SELECT 'Successfull!'

    SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM
COMMIT TRAN

PROBLEM:
IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) BEGIN
    SELECT @intErrorCode + 'Unexpected error occurred!'
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END

END
```

Comment: Could you post the value of `@var1` and `@var2`.. a `print` will do...

Comment: @Praveen Sure. Values are `@var1=2015-08-06 1:00 PM` & `@var2=2015-08-06 2:00 PM`

Comment: Could you provide some sample data for `@stBreakTimeStart` and `@stBreakTimeEnd`. Also the `@Log` value.

Comment: I have updated my question with test data. Please review.

Comment: I can't find that date format anywhere in the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx.

Comment: @adrianm If format is wrong then why this statement runs fine alone `select CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-08-06 1:00 PM')`. If you run this statement in store procedure inside cursor, it bombed.

Comment: The math for the conversion might as well happen outside the cursor.  You could, for testing, pull the select statement for EmpInOutAuto and put the math in the select statement. Actually, you don't need a cursor.  Do the insert into employees outside the cursor on the base cursor query using a left join to remove the ones that already exist, and then do the inserts into EmpinOut using a join concept back to employee on the same base cursor query.